# Why edit text preview is not showing properly....?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text which is showing preview as in the following image.

[image: device]

While I am entering the input, only half it is showing.After pressing back(soft keyboard dissappear) that time showing full text.

code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#D8D8D8" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="Register Now" android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="30dp">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:text=" First Name" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textColor="#6E6E6E"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:id="@+id/fname"
                android:singleLine="true" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:text=" Last Name" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textColor="#6E6E6E"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:id="@+id/lname"
                android:singleLine="true" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <TextView android:text=" Email" android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textColor="#6E6E6E"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp" android:id="@+id/email"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_bg" android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="80dp">
            <Button android:text="Register" android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textStyle="bold"></Button>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How to fix this problem...?

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: What is your edit_bg height & width?

Comment: Its an image of 273 X 36 pixels.

Comment: Your code is properly working in my application.

Comment: its works fine in emulator but not in device.

Comment: which device your are using. !samsung right.

Comment: its problem with your view. post your whole xml layout. once keyboard is shown all your layout is moving to upward right.

Comment: I have tried in Samsung GT-I5801, HTC desire, and in Alcate OT-890. In all these devices same problem. –

Comment: @PadmaKumar entire code updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in your layout design. you checked in low res screen.

```
Alcate OT-890 - 320 x 240 pixels, 2.8 in
Samsung GT-i5801 -240 x 400 px (3,2")
```

can u add  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your android manifest file of your activity.

//while keyboard is sliding/showing your are getting problem.
so remove the relative layout and try this below line.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="80dp">
            <Button android:text="Register" android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textStyle="bold"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you make the text inside a bit smaller the text will fit in.
Another idea is to remove `padding` if you have any inside the textview, or increase it's height.

Comment: I have tried changing the text size but same problem repeats..!

Comment: I still think that if you make your text a bit smaller for instance 12 dp it will fit :)

Answer (score 0):

set height of edittext as  android:layout_height="200dp" or some value and check once.

Comment: i have tried in my emulator it is working fine .just remove your drawable once and check it.

Comment: i have tried in samaung galaxy tab also by removing background drawable also it is working fine .

Comment: I have tried in Samsung GT-I5801, HTC desire, and in Alcate OT-890. In all these devices same problem.

Comment: whether you removed the drawable while checking?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following on an actual device, works perfectly.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=" Email"
            android:textColor="#6E6E6E"
            android:textSize="17dp" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not just a problem with the emulator? Have you tried a real device?

Comment: Its working fine in emulator...! problem is in only device..!